# What kind of kickstand mount is this?

Tags: kickstand

Which kickstands fit this bike? The old kickstand had 6mm bolts spaced 18mm apart, so I bought a "KSA18" kickstand, but it didn't fit. The KSA18 stand extended further than 9mm and had a small "hook" above the screws (the slot in the frame is flat). The old kickstand was an Ursus kickstand, but Ursus support thought it was a custom mount. Is the KSA18 standard available? I didn't find it on Google.

[image: Picture of kickstand mount]

Edit: It's an Ortler Bozen Performance (2019) bike produced by Derby Cycle Germany.

[image] <sub>Kickstand mount photo from https://www.probikeshop.com/en/gb/ortler-bozen-performance-electric-trekking-bike-black-2019/162662.html</sub>

Comment: The other option is to use a more generic stand.  Is there a chainstay bridge?    Ideally you'd want to be away from the brake rotor to protect it from damage and limit the chance of the stand jamming in the rotor.

Comment: Apparently there are KSA18 kickstands with a different geometry. See the Hebie Fix 18 *FC* for example which seems to match the triangular outline you have: https://www.boettcher-fahrraeder.shop/media/image/fd/1c/79/581157_7482B4BDCE7E41A5BC5B934B5033A9DE.jpg Unfortunately I can’t find a proper drawing with dimensions anywhere. Can’t you take a file and just adjust the kickstand’s mounting plate? :D Make sure to mount with threadlocker and proper torque.

Comment: That's the best photo I could find of how this bike's stand is attached.   If you have a better one please add.

Answer (score 1):

Not a strict answer to the question (it looks like a proprietary mount, as stated in the comments), but since it's not possible to add pictures in comments, I'll post it as answer.

Here's a picture of what a KSA 18 mount looks like. The hooks mentioned in the original question are meant to go around the embossment.

[image]